# How to delete data from SQLite?

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I want to delete data from SQLite table using code behind.

Comment: Which error message?

Comment: What does `ToList` do? Where do you think `RemoveAll` is removing **from**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are removing from the list, not from `Orders`
you can try like this

```
var toRemove = db.Orders.Where(x => x.OrderId == orderId);
db.Orders.RemoveRange(toRemove);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: thank you sir its working but I change `dbContext` to `db`

Comment: @raynaqarla yes my bad changed to `db` now, if its right please try to accept it cheers

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line:

```
db.Orders.ToList().RemoveAll(x => x.OrderId == orderId);
```

You remove item from materialized collection, not from database (after calling `ToList()` you got in memory collection, it can modified and database won't be updated). To remove item from database do:

```
var ordersToRemove = db.Orders.Where(x => x.OrderId == orderId);
db.Orders.RemoveRange(ordersToRemove);
```

Comment: I've try using your solution but its prompt an error which is `DBSet<Order> does not contain a definition for RemoveAll`

Answer (score -1):

You can try this Query
'Delete from (Table name) where (Condition);

Comment: this is not an answer.

Comment: While the title is "How to delete data from SQLite?" This question is not about SQL. I will recommend reading [How to build great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) guid lines. Citation: _"Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative. [...]"_